# Find mode without built in functions or dictionaries

Tags: python, list, max

So I have a list of values, and I have an idea of how to get the mode. But I'm unsure of how exactly to execute it. I know I will need the max value of the list using `max()` and also `for x in list`,and perhaps creating two lists, one for unique values and the other for how many times they appear, but besides that. I'm completely lost.
My list is:

```
 [0,68, 92, 68, 49, 43, 68]
```

**Expected output:**

```
68
```

Sorry if this is vague! This is not a duplicate. I don't want to use a counter function or dictionary. Only lists/ loops.

Comment: write your expected output

Comment: What's your expect output or result?

Comment: You say "without using built in functions" and "I know I will need [to use] max()". Which is it? Are you allowed to use builtins or not?

Comment: `lst = [0, 68, 92, 68, 49, 43, 68]

numbers = []
freq = []

for number in lst:
    if number not in numbers:
        numbers.append(number)
        freq.append(1)
    else:
        index = numbers.index(number)
        freq[index] += 1

mode = max(zip(numbers, freq), key = lambda x : x[1])[0]`

Comment: @Robᵩ Without built in functions such as Counter, Sum, or Mode. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The mode of a set of data values is the value that appears most often. You can easily get this using python's `Counter` module's `most_common` method. It takes `n` that defines how many results you want, `1` is the most common `2` would be the two most common.

```
from collections import Counter
data = Counter( [0,68, 92, 68, 49, 43, 68])
print data.most_common(1) 
> [(68, 3)]
```

> `most_common`: Return a list of the **n most common elements** and their counts from the most common to the least. If n is omitted or None, most_common() returns all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily: